# Magento - is it possible to set "Pagination Frame" from template/layout?

Tags: magento, mobile

I'm wondering if there's any way to set the "Pagination Frame" from either within a template phtml file, or from an xml layout file? So for example to change it from:

1 2 3 4 5 >

to

1 2 3 >

I'm working on a mobile theme, and I want to set the number of pages that are listed in the pagination. I know this can be set from the admin (Configuration -> Design -> Pagination -> Pagination Frame), but I want to keep that as it is, for desktop users, but set a lesser number of pages for mobile users.

Using the mobile themes catalog.xml file, I can set the number of products per page using the following:

```
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
```

Is there a similar version for setting number of pages in the pagination? Or else is there some way to set it from the mobile themes toolbar.phtml template, before the pager is grabbed? Something like:

```
$this->setFrameLength(3);
echo $this->getPagerHtml()
```

If that is possible somehow from the template file, is it also possible to set the number of products shown as well?

NOTE: The reason I want to set it from the template is so I can use a variable set from the admin module.

Comment: I don't think you can do that from view files, as the frame length is set in the block (`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar -> getPagerHtml()`), but you could easily overwrite it in a module, or even create an observer to set the value from a new variable you'd created in the configuration. If that would suits your need let me know and I'll explain further.

Comment: I'm already overriding the navigation so guess it's no harm to override the pager block too, can grab my admin variables there. Was just checking in case there was a simpler route! Out of interest, how would you use an observer in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the frame length by observer:

1. declare the observer:

   ```
   <frontend>
       ...
       <events>
           <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
               <observers>
                   <frame_length_according_to_useragent>
                       <type>singleton</type>
                       <class>yourmodulemodelalias/observer</class>
                       <method>setDifferentFrameLengthForMobileDevices</method>
                   </frame_length_according_to_useragent>
               </observers>
           </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
       </events>
       ...
   </frontend>
   ```
2. the method:

   ```
       public function setDifferentFrameLengthForMobileDevices($observer)
       {
           $event = $observer->getEvent();
           $block = $event->getBlock();
           if (get_class($block) == 'Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager') {
               //here some check of the user agent
               $block->setFrameLength(2);
           }
       }
   ```

   you will have to put the `$block->setFrameLength(2);` into an if() where you check the useragent. Also, you'll need to change the number "2" by a `Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame_for_mobile_devices')` where **pagination_frame_for_mobile_devices** will be a new config value you've created in your module's system.xml.

HTH

Comment: Cheers for this, interesting alright, would never have thought about doing it this way. Probably easier just overriding, but this is definitely useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that directly from template page/html/pager.phtml of your mobile theme and it works.

```
<?php $this->setFrameLength(2) ?>
```

Put it just before

```
<?php foreach ($this->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
```

I think it's better choice for supporting than events. Event base developing is nice for the one who do that. But it's a terrible legacy when the project passes to another developer or even development team.